# WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid

Tags: python, django

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),
)
```

This code returns the following error message:

```
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid
```

I do not understand what's wrong in this code. I tried to remove the comma but I get another error: `Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?`

Also when I insert a static path I get that error:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'F:/DEV/apps/myproject/static/',
)
```

And when I remove the path from `STATICFILES_DIRS` I don't get any error and the site works fine:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = () #no error
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the full exception traceback?

Comment: This code runs for me without error.  Need more code.

Comment: @Fuiba you need to post the full traceback, not a screenshot. Without knowing exactly what line is triggering this exception, it's tough to say. Your settings file don't appear to have any areas passing `abspath` a tuple. OSQA must be using `abspath` based on some setting.. but we can't tell without that traceback.

Comment: @Fuiba Your problem seems to be elsewhere.  What are you doing to generate this error?

Comment: @skzryzg Please read my question: the error comes only with this line: `os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static'),` if I remove this line I don't get any error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `abspath` in your `PROJECT_PATH`, use `dirname`.

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: Thank you @weasel but it doesn't work. I also tried with `PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)`

Comment: I tried to get the path of `STATICFILES_DIRS` from the logger and I get `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('F:/DEV/apps\\\\myproject\\\\static',)` with many slashes. So I tried to replace the 4 slashes with `.replace('\\','/')` but doesn't work.